# Buck Converter vs plain PWM Power modulation

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have a dc load that I'll be controlling with a fixed voltage DC source. The output of the load is proportional to the average power delivered (it's a heating element). Since the element is a fixed resistance (approximately) the power dissipated by the element is proportional to the voltage put across it. I have a 36 volt source, of which I wont need all 36 volts for most of its use--based on the likely amount of heat I'll need for my application. Is there any benefit to regulating the voltage down with a buck converter (i.e. with an inductor) vs just chopping the 36V with pwm to get the desired average power?

Would the case be different for a different type of a load such as a motor?

Comment: "Since the element is a fixed resistance (approximately) the power dissipated by the element is proportional to the voltage put across it." Power = V^2/R. So it is not proportional.

Comment: I think either one is fine. In fact, you can combine the two approaches by putting an inductor in series with the load. You would also want a filter cap. You don't need to use closed loop regulation if you are not worried about transient response. The output voltage will settle to Vin * duty cycle. Note that I have never tried this, but it is theoretically sound.

Comment: Indeed, its not *linearly* proportional to the voltage; however, I meant it in the more colloquial sense of 'increasing the voltage will increase the heat generated.' Yeah, that was maybe a bad choice of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purposes, a buck converter is simply a PWM stage with filtering.  Your heater load most likely won't care if it being fed smooth or choppy power.

The only time when it really makes a difference is if the sharp PWM edges might cause EMI or noise issues.  That's when filtering is required.

I'm assuming that you plant to have some form of active control on this: a temperature controller or whatever.  You want the heater to be able to run at full power when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This will work and in fact is used in many circuits. A brush DC motor in a RC toy is feed by PWM and speed of the motor is a function of a duty cycle. A light dimmer works on the same principle, even though the waveform is not rectangular.

Don't expect accuracy and also understand that time is often a factor. An electrical motor has max.torque (and power draw) when not rotating. The resistance of a cold heater is quite a bit smaller than that of a hot one. If you set some fixed duty cycle and never change it your heater will be heating up much slower.